# Firing page_publish where page is child page

Tags: pages, publish, child-pages

I'm having difficulty getting a function to fire when publishing a new page. I'd like it to fire when a new page is being published or edited but ONLY when that page has a parent.

Here's what I've got

```
function myFunction(){
    global $post; 
    if($post->post_parent > 0){
        // do stuff
    }   
}
add_action( 'publish_page', 'myFunction' );
```

So far this works when I'm updating a page, but not when I'm publishing one for the first time, it's not recognising that it has a parent at that point I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

The publish_page action is listed as deprecated.
You can use the 'transition_post_status' hook to check if a page was published.

```
function publish_page_interception( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( ($new_status != $old_status) && ($post->post_status == 'publish') && ($post->post_type == 'page') ) {
        if($post->post_parent > 0) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'publish_page_interception', 10, 3 );
```

Look here for further info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao